Difficult in reaching a web application through HTTPS
I have a web application deployed as a container in a Linux server in production. A certificate is from GeoTrust. It is a simple Python server using pfx. The web application is limited to internal only. The Linux server has a physical IP: 172.20.100.11 and a virtual IP: 172.16.100.162. The domain is linked to the virtual IP address.
Also:

The web application can be reached through HTTP, so there is no network connection problem
The Linux server has correct certificate store.
The same web application works with no problem in QA environment with the same pfx file for HTTPS, so the certificate should have no problem.

The differences between the QA and production:

The QA has only one physical IP, while the production has a physical IP and a virtual IP
The production has two domains for the same virtual IP address. When PING with mydomain, the response shows responding from the other domain, and vice versa.

In production, I can't make the HTTPS work, when run
curl -v https://mydomain
It returns the following error:

Rebuilt URL to: https://mydomain
Trying 172.16.100.162...
TCP_NODELAY set
connect to 172.16.100.162 port 443 failed: Connection timed out
Failed to connect to mydomain port 443: Connection timed out
Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to mydomain port 443: Connection timed out

I doubt either the double IP addresses for the same server or the double domains for the virtual IP could cause the problem of reaching HTTPS.
Can someone provide some help? Since I cannot access the production, troubleshooting isn't easy. But is it OK to support two domains on the same virtual IP? What is the correct way to make sure the setup supports physical IP and virtual IP for the same server?
Any help is greatly appreciated.
